# How to test WebSocket + PHP app?

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I have chat app written on php with websocket (Ratchet + ReactPHP).

I have some PHPUnit test for standalone classes. But i wont to test a whole functionality of my app.

How to do it? What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write PHPUnit tests for your whole project.

Here is a good guide, if you wanna test your whole project with PHPUnit and Selenium(a portable test framework):

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html

Comment: Your answer describes how to write tests in general - the question was about Ratchet, specifically. I'd like to see an example of how to mock the WS server and clients during testing, for example - if the transport layer is tested and trusted (which it is) then we should be able to write fast, synchronous test-suites for servers implemented in Ratchet, ignoring the transport layer and testing independently of a browser-based client or socket medium. But how?

Comment: Why would you mock anything when trying to test websockets?? This is not a unit test anymore, this is at least a functional test and there you don't have to mock anything